# clojure split string into different size chunks

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to split a string into n chunks of variable sizes.

As input I have a seq of the sizes of the different chunks:

```
(10 6 12)
```

And a string:

```
"firstchunksecondthirdandlast"
```

I would like to split the string using the sizes as so:

```
("firstchunk" "second" "thirdandlast")
```

As a newbie I still have a hard time wrapping my head around the most idiomatic way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is two ways to do this:

One version uses `reduce` which you can use very often if you want to carry some kind of state (here: The index where you're currently at). The reduce would need a `second` fn call applied to it to have the result in your form.

```
;; Simply take second as a result:
(let [s "firstchunksecondthirdandlast"]
  (reduce
    (fn [[s xs] len]
      [(subs s len)
       (conj xs (subs s 0 len))])
    [s []]
    [10 6 12]))
```

The other version first builds up the indices of start-end and then uses destructing to get them out of the sequence:

```
(let [s "firstchunksecondthirdandlast"]
  (mapv
    (fn [[start end]]
      (subs s start end))
    ;; Build up the start-end indices:
    (partition 2 1 (reductions + (cons 0 [10 6 12])))))
```

Note that neither of these are robust and throw ugly errors if the string it too short. So you should be much more defensive and use some asserts.

Comment: thank you very much for these two solutions!
I actually feel dumb, it is very different from what I'm used to do in pure Java

Answer (score 0):

Here is my go at the problem (still a beginner with the language), it uses an anonymous function and recursion until the chunks list is empty. I have found this pattern useful when wanting to accumulate results until a condition is met.

`str-orig chunks-orig []` sets the initial arguments for the anonymous function: the full string, full list of chunks and an empty `vec` to collect results into.

```
(defn split-chunks [str-orig chunks-orig]
  ((fn [str chunks result]
    (if-let [len (first chunks)] (recur
                                  (subs str len)
                                  (rest chunks)
                                  (conj result (subs str 0 len)))
      result))
   str-orig chunks-orig []))

(split-chunks "firstchunksecondthirdandlast" '(10 6 12))
; ["firstchunk" "second" "thirdandlast"]
```